pyenv-virtualenv activates but python version doesn’t change
I am trying to activate a virtual environment using pyenv-virtualenv on my M3 MacBook Air. After running pyenv activate computer_vision_env, the virtual environment appears to be activated (the terminal prompt shows (computer_vision_env)), but the Python version does not change as expected. When I run which python, it shows /Users/testuser/.pyenv/shims/python instead of the path to the virtual environment, /Users/testuser/.pyenv/versions/computer_vision_env/bin/python. As a result, any pip install commands do not install packages in the virtual environment.
I installed pyenv through Homebrew and added the following to my ~/.zshrc:
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
[[ -d $PYENV_ROOT/bin ]] && export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"

I created the virtual environment using pyenv virtualenv 3.10.15 computer_vision_env and then activated it with pyenv activate computer_vision_env. The terminal prompt changes as expected, but the Python version does not, and the installed packages (through pip install ...) go to the global environment instead of the virtual one.

echo $PATH ? which python ? which pip ? python --version ? pip --version ?
